# Issues trying to run moment-with-locales.js and moment using requireJs

Tags: momentjs

For a framework I'm working on I tried packaging moment-with-locales.js, moment.js and require Js together. If I run straight up moment and moment-locale without using requireJs, working fine. When I run with requireJs, locale is not working. Is there any reason why locale is not working?

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '.',
    paths: {
        'jQuery': '../path to jQuery plugin',
        'moment': '../path to moment js plugin',
        'momentLocale':'../path to moment locale js plugin',
        'momentTimeZone':'../path to moment timezone js plugin'
    },
    shim: {
        'moment': {
            deps: ['jQuery']
        },
        'momentLocale': {
            deps: ['moment']
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the JavaScript page

```
define([
    'jQuery',
    'moment',
    'momentLocale'],
    function(
        $,
        moment,
        momentLocale ) {
        getLocaleForCal: function(region) {
            switch(region): {
                case "af_NA":
                case "af_ZA":
                    return "af";
                break;
                default:
                    return "en";
                break;
            }
         }
     };
  });

$(function() {
    var currentRegion = this.getLocaleForCal("af_NA");
    $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker({
        locale: moment.locale(currentRegion)
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you follow [this guide](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/require-js/) from the official docs? Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Thanks quick reply VincezoC, I updated with my code.